# Running Mailman script as a service in Ubuntu/Monit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, monit

I have setup a mailman script in my rails app to download and process emails.  This is working fine.

The script is located in the scripts directory of the rails app.

I need this script to run upon deployment, via monit (which I am using for other services).

I am not sure how to configure monit to run this particular script (as it has no start/stop functions etc).

Using Ubuntu 12.04 on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty outdated question, but in case somebody is looking for the same - you can use gem [Daemons](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons) and create a wrapper script, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run('script/mailman_server')
```

Then you get `start` and `stop` commands and can do:

```
bundle exec script/mailman_daemon start
```

and

```
bundle exec script/mailman_daemon stop
```